# Is there a software on Ubuntu equal to Disk Drill on Windows

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, partitioning, data-recovery

I tried to recover my home folder, it was stored on it's own partition and I removed it by a mistake but no problem, I had a back up. Although I wanted to try to restore it so I used dd to create an image. By using `sudo tsk_recover -e /xxx/image.img /xxx/tsk/`I got 1000 files back but with "Disk Drill" on Windows I got the whole 40.000 files in great quality. My question is what did I wrong or is there something equal to Disk Drill on Linux?

Comment: TestDisk is a free and opensource, command-line data recovery tool that is used to recover data from deleted or lost partitions. Use it with caution! A guide on its installation and use: https://www.tecmint.com/install-testdisk-data-recovery-tool-in-linux/

Comment: Software recommendations are handled by another Q&A site, https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com